# python: extracted puzzled punctuation with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, twitter

I want to extract the puzzled punctuation(A combination of any number ! and ? in any order) from the following twitter text.

```
string4 = 'on my god!!!!,I think he is right?!, but what about he!??, but me !!??, yes !?!?, and my god ?!?.'
```

I use the following regex:

```
p_excitement = re.compile(r'!{1,}\?{1,}')

m = p_excitement2.findall(string4)
```

but the result is:

```
  ['!??', '!!??', '!?', '!?', '!?']
```

It is wrong. I hope to get the following result (please notice that I want to get any puzzled punctuation not just the following text):

```
  ['?!', '!??', '!!??', '!?!?', '?!?']
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could go for the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) and use

```
(([?!.])\2{1,})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[?!.]+
```

See [**a demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/nG7yX7/2).

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

string = "on my god!!!!,I think he is right?!, but what about he!??, but me !!??, yes !?!?, and my god ?!?."

rx = re.compile(r'(([?!.])\2{1,})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[?!.]+')
matches = [match.group(0)
            for match in rx.finditer(string)
            if match]
print(matches)
# ['?!', '!??', '!?!?', '?!?.']
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. I have updated my questions which the '!!!' is added, I do not want to extract the !!!

Comment: @tktktk0711: Why not? What is the rule here?

Comment: thanks for your comments @Jan. I am sorry for forgetting adding the !!! to the text since the '!!!' is in the text. I just want to extract the puzzled punctuation from the text

Comment: It should match `!!??`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
[?!]*(?:\!+\?+|\?+\!+)+[?!]*
```

See the  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW7cP6/3)

*Details*:

- `[?!]*` - zero or more `?` or `!` symbols
- `(?:\!+\?+|\?+!+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `\!+\?+` - 1+ `!`s followed with 1+ `?`s
  - `|` - or
  - `\?+!+` - 1+ `?`s`followed with 1+`!`s
- `[?!]*` - zero or more `?` or `!` symbols

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/myfIai):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[?!]*(?:\!+\?+|\?+\!+)+[?!]*')
s = "on my god!!!!,I think he is right?!, but what about he!??, but me !!??, yes !?!?, and my god ?!?."
print(p.findall(s))
# => ['?!', '!??', '!!??', '!?!?', '?!?']
```

Comment: FYI: the `(?:\!+\?+|\?+\!+)+` part *requires* consecutive `!`s and `?`s or `?`s and `!`s to appear at least once in the sequence to match it. A `(?:...)` non-capturing group is handy since the regex is used in `re.findall`.

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew, it seems that you are right (?:\!+\?+|\?+!+)+. I am confirming it.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
((?:\!+\?+)+!*|(?:\?+!+)+\?*)
```

- `(?:\!+\?+)+!*` Any combination of `[!?]` that  begins with `!` and may end to `?`
- `(?:\?+!+)+\?*` Any combination of `[!?]` that begins with `?` and may end to `!`

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM8dE1/1)**